# How to send json data to a Spring Controller?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC 3.0.7. I send data using AJAX to my Spring controller but the spring controller is not called. Here is my Ajax call:

```js
var mysaverowurl = '/app/user/save';
$.ajax({
  url: mysaverowurl,
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function () {
    alert("success ");
  }
});
```

postData contains `{"name":"Franck","age":"94"}`

Here is my Spring controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app/user")
public class myController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> saveUser(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @RequestBody User user) {
        List<String> reponse = null;
        // ...........
        return reponse;
    }
}
```

The controller is not called. But if remove `@RequestBody` from the `saveUser` signature:

```
public List<String> saveUser(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
```

it gets called. Why `@RequestBody` doesn't seem to work?

User class :

```
    public class User{

    private String name;

    private String age;

    public String getAge(){
      return age;
     }
    public void setAge(String age){
    this.age=age;
}
    public String getName(){
      return name;
     }
    public void setAge(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

    }
```

Here is a part of my pom file.

```
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
                 <version>1.8.1&</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should create a logger for `org.springframework.web` and set it to DEBUG level. Spring will tell exactly what happens. It will eliminate all the guessing what *might* be the problem.

Comment: Bart thanks for your suggestion. Do you know i set a logger to org.springframework.web ?

Comment: Yes but it's a whole different story. [Here's an article to get you started](http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/configure-logback-logging-with-spring/). I find Spring + SLF4J + Logback works best for me. Check for the latest version of SLF4J and LogBack in the maven repositories. This article is a bit out of date.

Comment: Show us your getters and seeters. They must be named appropriately.

Comment: Also, use your browsers network console to investigate what is actually sent in the ajax request body and headers.

Comment: I don't think it's relative to getters and getters. It the controller method which is not called

Comment: Before the controller method can get called, the `@RequestBody` argument must be constructed. For JSON content, Spring uses a Jackson `ObjectMapper` which uses your class' getters and setters to create the object. If those are not named properly, it can fail.

Comment: Everything looks to be in order. I would suggest you do what Bart said and configure logging for your application. Then set the level to `debug` and check what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `var mysaverowurl = '<c:url value="/app/user/save" />';` to

```
var mysaverowurl = '/app/user/save';
```

Comment: What do you think this will change?

Comment: URL is going as '<c:url value="/app/user/save" />' where as it should go '/app/user/save'

Comment: If it is within a JSP, then `<c:url value="/app/user/save" />` will be rendered as `/some-context/app/user/save`. If you are making the assumption that the javascript is not in a JSP, please make that clear.